# Один фон для двух блоков DIV

Tags: html, css

По сути нужно просто сделать фон правого блока чтобы он с увеличением левого блока, то же увеличивался, только как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посетить сервис http://csstemplater.com/ Сгенерировать все так как у Вас, внизу есть блок - Дополнительные опции: в котором нужно выбрать пункт - Эмулировать одинаковую высоту колонок. Скачать результат, посмотреть на CSS и HTML!